# How to wrap a div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, styles

I have a `selectbox`:

```html
<select>
  <option value="opt1">Optie nummer 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Optie nummer 2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Optie nummer 3</option>
</select>
```

With a plugin I style the select boxes and then the HTML become:

```html
<div class="sb-custom">
  <select tabindex="-1">
    <option value="opt1">Optie nummer 1</option>
    <option value="opt2">Optie nummer 2</option>
    <option value="opt3">Optie nummer 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="sb-select" readonly="readonly">

  <ul class="sb-dropdown">
    <li class="selected"><a href=".">Optie nummer 1</a></li>
    <li><a href=".">Optie nummer 2</a></li>
    <li><a href=".">Optie nummer 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want when I add the class `small` add the `selectbox` that the `div "sb-costum"` get a the class small extra. So you get `<div class="sb-custom small">`

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is unclear (to me at least :-). Thank you.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the question. Can you re-write the last paragraph to make a bit more sense? Perhaps give an example of what you'd like to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found my answer:**

```
$('.bottom table.form tr td select.small').parent(".sb-custom").addClass("small");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".sb-custom").addClass("small")
```

That should do it. See here for more details http://docs.jquery.com/Addclass

Comment: Nope.. then all the select boxes will wrap i only want that the selectbox with a class small will be wrapt.

Comment: Please can you post some before and after code. i.e. this is the HTML I've got, this is the HTML I need. That would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

hi here is one of the solutions to wrap and entire element into a div.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $('h3').each(function(){
          $(this).add( $(this).next() ).wrapAll('<div class="box"></div>');
         })
        })
```